# Jenkins in private subnet

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, build-pipeline, aws-vpc

For development environment, to be used by multiple developers, we have a pipeline to be created with Git-Jenkins-Tomcat(dev)
Do I need to place jenkins in private subnet and access thru bastion host?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it private either you need to setup a vpn so that you can access jenkins gui using http://private-subnet-ip:jenkins_port or you can move jenkins behind a load balancer and use load-balancer-dns to access jenkins gui. If it is in public subnet then use NACL/Security Groups to restrict access only to trusted sources. For more security, do not assign public ip to jenkins machine, assign dns hostname(even to load balancer you should do that) and implement ssl over http so that it can be accessed over https only.

Answer (score 0):

If in the same VPC the can talk to each other. If you are doing that from a public host "outside" the VPC then you need either allow the IP or connect from bastion host.

- You may need to explain more about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install docker and configure jenkins in that. so you can create and configure multi-nodes on that and it will consume time.